# jquery scroll to top animation

Tags: jquery

im trying to implement a scroll to top animation on my site 
http://www.cmclove.org/bootstrap

but whenever i scroll to top and try to scroll back down it seems like the page is fighting me and doesent want to go back down.

you might have to do it a couple of times and or try to scroll immediately back down after the animation finishes

heres the jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {

        /* set variables locally for increased performance */

        var scroll_timer;
        var displayed = false;
        var $message = $('#message a');
        var $window = $(window);
        var top = $(document.body).children(0).position().top;

        /* react to scroll event on window */
        $window.scroll(function(e) {

            window.clearTimeout(scroll_timer);
            e.preventDefault();
            scroll_timer = window.setTimeout(function(e) {
                if ($window.scrollTop() <= top) {
                    displayed = false;
                    $message.fadeOut(800);
                    e.preventDefault();

                }
                else if (displayed == false) {
                    displayed = true;
                    $message.stop(true, true).show(1000).click(function(e) {
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: 0
                        }, 'slow');
                        $message.fadeOut(1000);
                        e.preventDefault();


                    });
                }

            }, 100);
        });
    });
});​
```

heres the html

```
  <a id="top"></a>

  <!--- all my html stuff -->

  <div id="message"><a href="#top"></a></div>
  </footer>
```

Comment: Do you have to have 'html' and 'body' selected in the scroll animation?

Comment: Unlike `return false`, `preventDefault()` is commonly placed at the top of the function.  Also, a jsFiddle demo would be helpful.

Comment: yes i have html body selected in the scroll animation is it because im not adding prevent default to the top of the function thats causing the bug?

Comment: It happens because when you physically scroll, the timer is still running and tries to finish the easing.

After the easing finished, your physical scroll and the timed scroll won't interfere.

Comment: I am making a comment to let you know that `preventDefault()` is not placed properly.  Sometimes it makes a difference, and it certainly wouldn't hurt to fix this.  However, in your case, I think you have a flaw with the logic.  See comment by heartcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what is happening. You are binding a new 'click' event every time 'scroll to top' happens. And since they add up, every time the scroll bar freezes for 1 second more. So the first time you scroll to top, nothing freezes. Next time it freezes for a second, next time for 2 seconds and etc.

I think you need:

```
$message.unbind('click');
```

right before:

```
$message.stop(true, true).show(1000).click(function(e) {
```

i.e.:

```
else if (displayed == false) {
  displayed = true;
  $message.unbind('click');
  $message.stop(true, true).show(1000).click(function(e) {
  ...
```

If you don't believe me, make it freeze by doing a couple of times 'go to top', then write this in the Firebug console:

```
$('#message a').unbind('click');
```

and try it again. You will see that the freezing is gone (until you accumulate it again with multiple bindings of 'click' event).

Cheers.

Comment: also note that the 'e.preventDefault();' call inside the timer function throws an error: e is undefined.

Comment: yeah i fixed that after i posted the question up i also took the other guys advice and added the prevent default right after the function...im still new to jquery and learning all the proper syntax and stuff